# Fisher's Exact in scipy as new column using pandas

Tags: pandas, scipy, jupyter-notebook

Using ipython notebook, a pandas dataframe has 4 columns:  **numerator1**, **numerator2**, **denominator1** and **denominator2**.

Without iterating through each record, I am trying to create a fifth column titled FishersExact.  I would like the value of the column to store the tuple returned by [scipy.stats.fisher_exact](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html#scipy.stats.fisher_exact) using values (or some derivation of the values) from each of the four columns as my inputs.

```
df['FishersExact'] = scipy.stats.fisher_exact( [[df.numerator1, df.numerator2],
[df.denominator1 - df.numerator1 , df.denominator2 - df.numerator2]])
```

Returns:

```
/home/kevin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/stats.pyc in fisher_exact(table, alternative)
2544     c = np.asarray(table, dtype=np.int64)  # int32 is not enough for the algorithm
2545     if not c.shape == (2, 2):
-> 2546         raise ValueError("The input `table` must be of shape (2, 2).")
2547 
2548     if np.any(c < 0):

ValueError: The input `table` must be of shape (2, 2).
```

When I index only the first record of the dataframe:

```
odds,pval = scipy.stats.fisher_exact([[df.numerator1[0], df.numerator2[0]], 
[df.denominator1[0] - df.numerator1[0], df.denominator2[0] -df.numerator2[0]]])
```

This is returned:

```
1.1825710754 0.581151431104
```

I'm essentially trying to emulate the arithmetic functionality similar to:

```
df['freqnum1denom1'] = df.numerator1 / df.denominator1
```

which returns a new column added to the dataframe where each records' frequency is in the new column.

Probably missing something, any direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're building a matrix of `pandas` series, and passing it to the function. The function wants a matrix of scalars; you can call it multiple times. These two things are not quite the same.

There are (at least) two ways to go here.

**Using `apply`**

You could use `pandas`'s [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for this.

```
df['FishersExact'] = df.apply(
    lambda r: scipy.stats.fisher_exact([[r.numerator1, ... ]]),
    axis=1)
```

Note the following:

- `axis=1` applies a function to each row.
- Within the `lambda`, `r.numerator` is a scalar.

**Back To Basics**

[Fischer's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) can be described as vectorized operations in the original columns, which should be much faster. To increase the speed to the maximum, you need to use a vectorized version of factorial (which I don't know). This could even be a separate (good!) SO question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, your suggestion executed, however my table is over 200K rows and the execution has slowed my computer to a halt.  
tested on 10 rows with .head() and returned a fifth column with exactly what I asked for.  Thank you!

Comment: Added a blurb on faster exec. I think you need to ask a bit further on some point. See above.

Comment: Please see my answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/34947578/… It computes the answer for millions of rows in a few seconds :)

Comment: @unfuncat Cool!