# How to vectorize Fisher's exact test?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

Is it possible, and if so how, to optimize this calculation using the vectorization of Fisher's exact test? Runtime is cumbersome when `num_cases` > ~1000000.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact

num_cases = 100
randCounts = np.random.random_integers(100,size=(num_cases,4))

def testFisher(randCounts):
    return [fisher_exact([[r[0],r[1]],[r[2], r[3]]])[0] for r in randCounts]

In [6]: %timeit testFisher(randCounts)
        1 loops, best of 3: 524 ms per loop
```

Comment: It seems, the described problem is not pandas specific. You rather ask for a vectorized version of scipy.stats.fisher_exact that handles a vector of 2x2 matrices. Maybe reformulate the problem without pandas. Furthermore, you ask "is it possible". The nasty answer could be yes, as pointed out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30309509/5142797. Maybe rather ask how is it possible.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm trying to ask.  Is it necessary to vectorize the `fisher_exact` though?  I'd like to apply the concept to other statistical methods also.

Comment: Yeah, it's necessary to vectorize fisher_exact (which means first vectorizing factorial).  Currently your computation time is just linear in num_cases.  Vectorizing is a way to improve on that.  Possibly cython or numba could help, but only if the scipy version of fisher_exact isn't already cythonized (which I assume it is, but don't know for a fact).

Comment: Seems to be pure python: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/stats/stats.py

Comment: So I'm speculating a little, but exact fisher depends on factorial and it looks like the problem may be that large factorials can exceed the bounds of a numpy integer, which makes it hard for this to have a fast implementation (so that's why it's in pure python?) -- as big ints are going to be objects.  I suspect for cases where speed matters, folks are going to be using some test that is approximate (and based on floats not integers) rather than exact.  Dunno though, this is beyond my knowledge and also starts to be a statistics question, not a programming question.

Comment: I hope this doesn't turn into a statistics question.  Just looking for ideas/resources on speeding this up.

Comment: But sometimes they are inherently connected.  You might have the choice of a fast approximation or a slow exact answer.  Often in statistics an approximation is just as good as an exact answer (as a practical concern, at least).

Comment: `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` is an implemented approximation of Fisher's exact test. It speeds things up by a factor of 10 on my machine. From the docu: "An often quoted guideline for the validity of this calculation is that
the test should be used only if the observed and expected frequency in
each cell is at least 5."

Comment: I created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/arvkevi/fcd356bb97b960043e29b540b3508744) which tries an implementation of a vectorized form of this function, but `alternative="two-sided"` is very slow (I think) because `binary_search` isn't vectorized.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer using fisher exact as implemented in [fisher](https://github.com/brentp/fishers_exact_test). I compute the OR by hand in numpy.

Install:

```
# pip install fisher
# or 
# conda install -c bioconda fisher
```

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
num_cases = 100
c = np.random.randint(100,size=(num_cases,4), dtype=np.uint)

# head, i.e. 
c[:5]
# array([[44, 47, 64, 67],
#   [67,  9, 83, 21],
#   [36, 87, 70, 88],
#   [88, 12, 58, 65],
#   [39, 87, 46, 88]], dtype=uint64)
```

Execute:

```
from fisher import pvalue_npy
_, _, twosided = pvalue_npy(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3])
odds = (c[:, 0] * c[:, 3]) / (c[:, 1] * c[:, 2])

print("result fast p and odds", odds[0], twosided[0])
# result fast p and odds 0.9800531914893617 1.0
print("result slow", fisher_exact([[c[0][0], c[0][1]], [c[0][2], c[0][3]]]))
# result slow (0.9800531914893617, 1.0)
```

Note that for one million rows it only takes two seconds :)

Also, to compute an approximate OR you might want to add a pseudocount to the table before finding the oddsratio. This is often more interesting than inf, since you can compare the approximations :) :

```
c2 = c + 1
odds = (c2[:, 0] * c2[:, 3]) / (c2[:, 1] * c2[:, 2])
```

Edit:

from 0.0.61>= this method is included in [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) as `pr.stats.fisher_exact`.