# Pandas vectorize statistical odds-ratio test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statistics

I'm looking for a faster way to do odds ratio tests on a large dataset. I have about 1200 variables (see var_col) I want to test against each other for mutual exclusion/ co-occurrence. An odds ratio test is defined as (a * d) / (b * c)), where a, b c,d are number of samples with (a) altered in neither site x & y  (b) altered in site x, not in y (c) altered in y, not in x (d) altered in both. I'd also like to calculate the fisher exact test to determine statistical significance. The scipy function fisher_exact can calculate both of these (see below).

```
#here's a sample of my original dataframe
sample_id_no  var_col
       0    258.0
       1    -24.0
       2   -150.0
       3    149.0
       4    108.0
       5   -126.0
       6    -83.0
       7      2.0
       8   -177.0
       9   -171.0
      10     -7.0
      11   -377.0
      12   -272.0
      13     66.0
      14    -13.0
      15     -7.0
      16      0.0
      17    189.0
      18      7.0
      13    -21.0
      19     80.0
      20    -14.0
      21    -76.0
       3     83.0
      22   -182.0

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import fisher_exact
import itertools

#create a dataframe with each possible pair of variable
var_pairs = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.combinations(df.var_col.unique(),2) )).rename(columns = {0:'alpha_site', 1: 'beta_site'})

#create a cross-tab with samples and vars
sample_table = pd.crosstab(df.sample_id_no, df.var_col)

odds_ratio_results = var_pairs.apply(getOddsRatio, axis=1, args = (sample_table,))

#where the function getOddsRatio is defined as:
def getOddsRatio(pairs, sample_table):   

    alpha_site, beta_site = pairs
    oddsratio, pvalue = fisher_exact(pd.crosstab(sample_table[alpha_site] > 0, sample_table[beta_site] > 0))
    return ([oddsratio, pvalue])
```

This code runs very slow, especially when used on large datasets. In my actual dataset, I have around 700k variable pairs. Since the getOddsRatio() function is applied to each pair individually, it is definitely the main source of the slowness. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Generic advice, but if you can use numpy arrays instead of pandas dataframes, you'll see a speedup. Ditto if you use ints instead of floats. I haven't been able to figure out your function well enough to write up a demo. Can you do it with numpy slicing instead of named pandas columns? The pandas crosstab (your code generated two?) is a slow step, correct?

Comment: Sure - I'll see what I can do and update my post accordingly. I believe the slowest part is the apply function (getOddsRatio), which in itself creates a crosstab. I think this is because in my actual dataset I have around 700k variable pairs and the apply function is applied individually to each pair. Hope this explanation helps - I can explain it in more detail if you'd like.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947578/how-to-vectorize-fishers-exact-test It computes the answer for millions of rows in a few seconds :)