# Fishers Exact Test from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statistics, combinations

I'm trying to work out the best way to create a p-value using Fisher's Exact test from four columns in a dataframe.  I have already extracted the four parts of a contingency table, with 'a' being top-left, 'b' being top-right, 'c' being bottom-left and 'd' being bottom-right.  I have started including additional calculated columns via simple pandas calculations, but these aren't necessary if there's an easier way to just use the 4 initial columns.  I have over 1 million rows when including an additional set (x.type = high), so want to use an efficient method.  So far this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import math
path = r'directory_path'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame['a+b'] = frame['a'] + frame['b']
frame['c+d'] = frame['c'] + frame['d']
frame['a+c'] = frame['a'] + frame['c']
frame['b+d'] = frame['b'] + frame['d']
```

As an example of this data, 'frame' currently shows:

```
    ID(n)   a   b   c   d   i   x.name  x.type  a+b     c+d     a+c     b+d
0   1258065     5   28  31  1690    1754    Albumin     low     33  1721    36  1718
1   1132105     4   19  32  1699    1754    Albumin     low     23  1731    36  1718
2   898621  4   30  32  1688    1754    Albumin     low     34  1720    36  1718
3   573158  4   30  32  1688    1754    Albumin     low     34  1720    36  1718
4   572975  4   23  32  1695    1754    Albumin     low     27  1727    36  1718
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
666646  12435   1   0   27  1726    1754    WHR     low     1   1753    28  1726
666647  15119   1   0   27  1726    1754    WHR     low     1   1753    28  1726
666648  17053   1   2   27  1724    1754    WHR     low     3   1751    28  1726
666649  24765   1   3   27  1723    1754    WHR     low     4   1750    28  1726
666650  8733    1   1   27  1725    1754    WHR     low     2   1752    28  1726
```

Is the best way to convert these to a numpy array and process it through iteration, or keep it in pandas?  I assume that I can't use math functions within a dataframe (I've tried `math.comb()`, which didn't work in a dataframe).  I've also tried using [pyranges](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/pyranges) for its fisher method but it seems it doesn't work with my environment (python 3.8).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947578/how-to-vectorize-fishers-exact-test) which came from the author of pyranges (i think), let's say you data is something like:

```
import pandas as pd 
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(1000000,4)))
df.columns=['a','b','c','d']
df['ID'] = range(1000000)

df.head()

    a   b   c   d   ID
0   85  85  85  87  0
1   20  42  67  83  1
2   41  72  58  8   2
3   13  11  66  89  3
4   29  15  35  22  4
```

You convert it into a numpy array and did it like in the post:

```
c = df[['a','b','c','d']].to_numpy(dtype='uint64')

from fisher import pvalue_npy

_, _, twosided = pvalue_npy(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3])
df['odds'] = (c[:, 0] * c[:, 3]) / (c[:, 1] * c[:, 2])

df['pvalue'] = twosided
```

Or you can fit it directly:

```
_, _, twosided = pvalue_npy(df['a'].to_numpy(np.uint), df['b'].to_numpy(np.uint), 
                            df['c'].to_numpy(np.uint), df['d'].to_numpy(np.uint))

df['odds'] = (df['a'] * df['d']) / (df['b'] * df['c'])
df['pvalue'] = twosided
```

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I'm getting errors with this.  For the fisher package method I get: 
```ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-e90fc90e0b5d> in <module>
      1 c = df[['a','b','c','d']].to_numpy(dtype='uint64')
----> 2 _, _, twosided = pvalue_npy(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3])
      3 df['odds'] = (c[:, 0] * c[:, 3]) / (c[:, 1] * c[:, 2])
      4 
      5 df['pvalue'] = twosided

src\cfisher.pyx in cfisher.pvalue_npy()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'uint_t' but got 'unsigned long long'.```

Comment: For the other method, I get (shortened):
```ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e78d1c46fba1> in <module>
      2                             df['c'].to_numpy(np.uint), df['d'].to_numpy(np.uint))
      3 
----> 4 df['odds'] = (df['a'] * df['d']) / (df['b'] * df['c'])
      5 df['pvalue'] = twosided

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero```

Comment: for the 2nd  you need to add a psuedo count, but the pvalue works right. Just do (df['a']+0.5)*(df['d']+0.5) / ((df['b'] +0.5)* (df['c']+0.5))

Comment: the first one.. i think you are doing something weird..do ```type(c[0,0])``` you should see that it is ```numpy.uint64```

Comment: Ah I see.  I don't think I need an odds ratio anyway for now.  The p_value results as slightly different to those I calculated in excel, is that to do with accuracy of rounding?  E.g. 0.000429 instead of 0.000393 in Excel, and 0.001003 instead of 0.000933.  I'm assuming numpy would be more accurate?

Comment: type(c[0,0]) gives numpy.uint64.  This is the code for that one:
```c = df[['a','b','c','d']].to_numpy(dtype='uint64')

_, _, twosided = pvalue_npy(c[:, 0], c[:, 1], c[:, 2], c[:, 3])

df['pvalue'] = twosided```

Comment: I don't use excel so I cannot comment on that. It's When one of the numbers (a,b,c or d) get large, it might be difficult to estimate the two sided p value. You are doing a lot of test, so something in the ball park should be ok.

Comment: FYI, I just changed ```c = df[['a','b','c','d']].to_numpy(dtype='uint64')``` to ```c = df[['a','b','c','d']].to_numpy(dtype='uint')``` and it seems to work ok now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222402/discussion-between-dave-c-and-stupidwolf).